# Is this transform linear: $T(a,b,c) = (\ a+2,\ \ b-c,\ \ 5c\ )$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is from chapter on Matrix Linear Transformations in Linear algebra textbook.

> Is the the following transform linear:
>
> $$T(a,b,c) = (\ a+2,\ \ b-c,\ \ 5c\ )$$

Book says:

$$T(a=0,b=0,c=0) = (\ 2,\ \ 0,\ \ 0\ ) \ne (0,0,0)$$

Therefore not linear.

My question is:  What linearity property is this proving?

I have only two listed in this chapter:

$$T(v+w)=T(v) + T(w)$$

$$T(\alpha v) = \alpha T(v)$$

Maybe they left out a property need to prove this?

Comment: Try T ( 0 (a,b,c))

Comment: I can't integrate this: "Try (0(a, b,c)) Integrate this!"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, from the first property we have $$T(0)= T(0+0)=T(0)+T(0)\implies T(0)=0$$

So if $T(0)\ne 0$ then this transformation is not linear.

Comment: haha...ok... missed that one..

Comment: OP has changed hiis/her question.

Comment: T(0) = (2,0,0)  and T(0) + T(0) = (4,0,0)?

Comment: Yes,..................

Comment: I was thinking they had some requirement that the t0 vector needs to be included to be a vector space...but on the otherhand, why does that need to correspond to the converting the zero vector...with T...